# actionbarsherlock simulate tabhost behavior?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

Is there a simple way to be able to access all the data fields on all the ABS fragments like I could using just TabHost from a single button onclick listener?

In ABS I am trying to have some fragments that display swipey forms to a user.

And when the user is finished completing all the forms then I want a button that can be used to gather up all the user data from all the fragments and save it (preferences) and also send it.

Likewise when the app starts I want it to be able to load in their previous inputs back into all the forms (fragments) so the user doesn't have to re-enter everything.

I have done similar things in the past using TabHost but those were not swipey and now feel out of date.

So is there a pattern for ActionBarSherlock fragments like this?

I have other apps where I have used TabHost and was able to access all the content in all the Tabs through TabHost so it was easy to gather up all the data.

But with the ABS fragments it seems that the data fields go out of scope such that findViewById fails for elements that are not on the current fragment.

So far the only thing I've found is using a complicated callback mechanism to the activity.  But that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewPager setOffscreenPageLimit seems to do what I need.

findViewById no longer fails.